# How can I deploy my .vimrc on Divio-Cloud to use with a ssh connection?

Tags: vim, divio

I want to make some changes on my project with vim through a ssh-connection to Divio-Cloud. How can I deploy my .vimrc to be used by the Vim on Divio-Cloud. Till now it just uses a bare-bonded version without code-highlighting etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSH to connect to Divio-Cloud, and open Vim there, you can use `SCP` to copy your local `~/.vimrc` to the remote host, and then restart Vim there. (With an active SSH connection, and the appropriate `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` configuration in `~/.ssh/config`, the connection will even be shared and you won't be prompted for a password for the remote copy.)

You can also use other (SSH-based) synchronization methods, like `rsync` or `unison` to keep your configuration up-to-date and in sync.

Alternatively, you could use Vim on your local system, and open the remote files in it, via the [`:help netrw`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#pi_netrw.txt) plugin that ships with Vim: `:edit scp://hostname/path/to/file`.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. But it doesn't work. I copied my .vimrc to Divio-Cloud but it will not be recogniced. Maybe it's because of the Docker architecture.

Comment: Vim expects the config under `~/.vimrc`. Have you copied it there? If yes, `:edit $MYVIMRC` should open it. Else, check `:scriptnames` output for what actually is sourced, and follow `:help initialization` to troubleshoot further.

Comment: There may be an issue with permissions as well. Check the permissions on the copied .vimrc on the new system.